# Make a grid of lines with a For[] loop inside a manipulate statement

Tags: graphics, manipulate

can anyone help me? I'm tring to write a `Manipulate[]` statement that can be able to modify a grid of lines in length, height and change the space between them. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: How about `ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[0, 1], Mesh -> {5, 10}, MeshShading -> None, MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0, 1], PlotStyle -> None]`? You didn't mention what you'll be using the grid for.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

`For` is highly inefficient in *Mathematica*; I recommend something else.

For instance:

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[ConstantArray[, {ly, lx}], Frame -> All, 
  ImageSize -> {(d + 1) lx + 1, (d + 1) ly + 1}], {{lx, 3}, 1, 10, 
  1}, {{ly, 3}, 1, 10, 1}, {{d, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

Comment: Damn, I was only 2/3th there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code, using `Table[]`

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Table[{EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[White], 
    Rectangle[{a i, b j}, {(i + 1) a, (j + 1) b}]}, {i , 0, ni}, {j , 
    0, nj}]], {a, 0.1, 2, 0.1}, {b, 0.1, 2, 0.1}, {ni, 1, 10, 1}, {nj,
   1, 10, 1}]
```